# Blackberry10: How to get current security perimeter in which the app is running?

Tags: native, blackberry-10

I have found this in documentation:
http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__system__securityperimeter.html

but it just lists possible security perimeters. How do I get current security perimeter for my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two methods to do this:

1. you can check your application's path for "-enterprise", for example this app is installed in "work space":
   "/accounts/1000-enterprise/appdata/com.example.Test.testDev_nEncryptionb8c278e8.entr/data"
2. you can check content of PERIMETER environment variable. Possible values are "personal" and "enterprise".

These methods are not officially supported.